# R: is it possible to return the last value from a `source`?

Tags: r

I put some value in a file e.g. `code.R` and inside it I put

`1`

when I `source(code.R)` It doesn't return the value inside?

Is there a way to `source` a value and have that `source` function return the value in the code?

Comment: Assign a variable to your 1 or any other expression, then after `source`  that variable will show up in your environment.

Comment: that is my current approach which resutls in code that looks like `{source(file, local=TRUE), value}` which is not as clean as `{source(file, some_options)}`

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Please post fuller background of your x problem not just your y solution of `source`.

Comment: I think you have to explicitly say `print` or `cat` for what you want printed.

Comment: Have you tried `source(code.R)$value`? It should contain the results of the last expression evaluated. Though this way of using `source` is not recommended.

Comment: @MrFlick I would accept that as the answer.